# Smoothen out edge after deletion

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I 3D scanned my face to create a mask for my self for this halloween. I have already removed the unwanted details and just leave the things I want.

But I am now left with those spikes around the mask and the the whole around the eyes. How do I smoothen this out?

My 3rd day in blender. Please do not hurt me. I can not find any reference how to smoothen it. I thought doing S + X + 0 will help but it did not

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick and dirty method would be to use the circle select tool to quickly remove the strays—but that will not create sharp edges or a completely smooth mesh.

Have you tried the Subsurface Modifier? That could help. It is an absolute fundamental to smoothing a mesh and a MUST-learn.

But from a more professional standpoint—the topology of this model is way too complicated. The scan has created an accurate but wildly complicated form that contains triangles (the worst when you are creating almost anything—especially here when they are tiny).

The ultimate (and most correct) workflow from here, to my knowledge, would be to retopologize the face. There are YouTube tutorials on “Retopo” and it’s worth the time to learn. This mask you have is what all game characters look like when they’re first sculpted—very complicated and dense with miniature triangles—then they have to go back and create a final clean version using the Retopo technique.

John

Comment: Let me just say, since this may be a one-off project for you. Use the circle-select (or just regular selection, for that matter) to manually get rid of the dramatic flyaways. Then add a Subsurface Modifier and see where that gets you. If it bogs down your system or has trouble, try applying a Decimate modifier to simplify the mesh first. Then print your mask and sand off the remaining jagged artifacts.

Comment: Thank you! These modifiers helped a lot. I used Decimate and Smooth but I have to re sculpture again because of too much smoothing, it removes a lot of the details but that's ok. I'll add these modifiers first soon before re-sculpturing

Comment: Happy to help. So if you’re ultimately going to resurface/retopologize, you don’t need to decimate or smooth because you’re going to manually retrace the model onto a new mesh anyways. Decimate/Subsurf would be if you want to use that mesh and want to clean it up. Just out of curiosity, how did you scan your face?